# What is the difference between the verbs "bewerten" and "einschätzen"?

Tags: meaning, difference, verb

Is there a difference between the meaning of *bewerten* and *einschätzen* when used?  I cannot tell the difference between both and the dictionary definitions for both are practically identical.  It would help to know, for example, when I can use one and noth the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Einschätzen" und "bewerten" both mean basically "to assess", but with different nuances or connotations.

"Einschätzen" more strongly emphasises the "schätzen" ("estimate") aspect of assessing something. "Bewerten" at least purports more of an objective assessment or measurement.

Additionally, "bewerten" mostly means to assess the value ("Wert") of something, monetary or otherwise. "Einschätzen" can mean to assess something with regard to about any quality or trait.

Answer (score 2):

"Bewerten" means to give something a value (on a scale, e.g. a grade).  "Einschätzen" is more general. A result of an "Einschätzung" could be also a grade but also a simple "good", "bad" or "impossible" or anything else that reflects an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that *einschätzen* is more guesswork, while *bewerten* carries more confidence. For example:

> Wie schätzen Sie die Chancen der Kandidaten ein?

The question implies that the answer cannot be more than an educated guess.

In contrast:

> Wie bewerten Sie das Ergebnis der Wahl?

This implies that there are some objective criteria that allow a judgement.

Answer (score 0):

"Bewerten" refers to "worth," in an objective, often numeric sense. Man wird die Waren *bewerten.*

""Einschätzen" refers to "value," in a subjective, qualitative sense. Man wird die Gedichte *einschätzen.*